# Asynctask in fragment is not getting to onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, httpurlconnection, gson

I am using openweathermap api (5 day forecast) and I'm parsing the data with GSON. The asynctask connects with the server but its not going to the onPostExecute.It terminates once it gets the response 200 code. I think it set up correctly but its not finishing the program:

```
   private static class GetWeatherAync extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, List<ForecastWeatherList>> {
    private String TAG = GetWeatherAync.class.getSimpleName();
    private final String serviceUrl;
    private Context mContext;
    private Listener listener;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;


    public GetWeatherAync(Listener listener, Object mStatusView, Object api_key) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.serviceUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + "Baltimore" + api_key;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ForecastWeatherList> doInBackground(Context...params) {
        try {
            Log.d("debugMode", "The application is in doInBackground");

            URL url = new URL(serviceUrl);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                // If the request was successful (response code 200),
                // then read the input stream and parse the response.
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Response code:" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    ForecastWeatherListWrapper weatherWrapper = new Gson().fromJson(bufferedReader, ForecastWeatherListWrapper.class);
                    return weatherWrapper.getforecastWeatherLists();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


        return null;


    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ForecastWeatherList> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "populate UI recycler view with gson converted data");
            listener.afterSearch(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat: 
E/GetWeatherAync: Response code:200

Here is my forecastweatherlistwrapper:

```
 public class ForecastWeatherListWrapper {

 @SerializedName("list")
 @Expose
 private List<ForecastWeatherList> forecastWeatherLists;

 public List<ForecastWeatherList> getforecastWeatherLists() {
    return forecastWeatherLists;
}

public void setforecastWeatherLists(List<ForecastWeatherList>      
forecastWeatherItems){

   this.forecastWeatherLists = forecastWeatherItems;
       }
}



public class ForecastWeatherList {
@SerializedName("dt")
@Expose
private Integer dt;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private Main main;
@SerializedName("weather")
@Expose
private Weather weather = null;
@SerializedName("clouds")
@Expose
private Clouds clouds;
@SerializedName("wind")
@Expose
private Wind wind;
@SerializedName("rain")
@Expose
private Rain rain;
@SerializedName("sys")
@Expose
private Sys sys;
@SerializedName("dt_txt")
@Expose
private String dtTxt;

public Integer getDt() {
    return dt;
}

public void setDt(Integer dt) {
    this.dt = dt;
}

public Main getMain() {
    return main;
}

public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public Weather getWeather() {
    return (Weather) weather;
}

public void setWeather(Weather weather) {
    this.weather = weather;
}

public Clouds getClouds() {
    return clouds;
}

public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
    this.clouds = clouds;
}

public Wind getWind() {
    return wind;
}

public void setWind(Wind wind) {
    this.wind = wind;
}

public Rain getRain() {
    return rain;
}

public void setRain(Rain rain) {
    this.rain = rain;
}

public Sys getSys() {
    return sys;
}

public void setSys(Sys sys) {
    this.sys = sys;
}

public String getDtTxt() {
    return dtTxt;
}

public void setDtTxt(String dtTxt) {
    this.dtTxt = dtTxt;
}



  }
```

Here are my some of  GSON classes to parse JSON data. Some classes are Main, Clouds, etc

Here is my main class:

```
public class Main {

@SerializedName("temp")
@Expose
private Double temp;
@SerializedName("temp_min")
@Expose
private Double tempMin;
@SerializedName("temp_max")
@Expose
private Double tempMax;
@SerializedName("pressure")
@Expose
private Double pressure;
@SerializedName("sea_level")
@Expose
private Double seaLevel;
@SerializedName("grnd_level")
@Expose
private Double grndLevel;
@SerializedName("humidity")
@Expose
private Integer humidity;
@SerializedName("temp_kf")
@Expose
private Integer tempKf;

public Double getTemp() {
    return temp;
}

    public void setTemp(Double temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public Double getTempMin() {
        return tempMin;
    }

    public void setTempMin(Double tempMin) {
        this.tempMin = tempMin;
    }

    public Double getTempMax() {
        return tempMax;
    }

    public void setTempMax(Double tempMax) {
        this.tempMax = tempMax;
    }

public Double getPressure() {
    return pressure;
}

public void setPressure(Double pressure) {
    this.pressure = pressure;
}

public Double getSeaLevel() {
    return seaLevel;
}

public void setSeaLevel(Double seaLevel) {
    this.seaLevel = seaLevel;
}

public Double getGrndLevel() {
    return grndLevel;
}

public void setGrndLevel(Double grndLevel) {
    this.grndLevel = grndLevel;
}

public Integer getHumidity() {
    return humidity;
}

public void setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
    this.humidity = humidity;
}

public Integer getTempKf() {
    return tempKf;
}

public void setTempKf(Integer tempKf) {
    this.tempKf = tempKf;
}

  }
```

Here is my weather class:

```
public class Weather {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private String main;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("icon")
@Expose
private String icon;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMain() {
    return main;
}

public void setMain(String main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(String icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}


  }
```

Here is my raw string data (I think).

```
 "cod":"200",
"message":0.0074,
  "cnt":39,
"list":[
  {
     "dt":1534215600,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.24,
        "temp_min":292.346,
        "temp_max":293.24,
        "pressure":1021.77,
        "sea_level":1028.21,
        "grnd_level":1021.77,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.89
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":20
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.51,
        "deg":275.001
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":0.0050000000000008
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 03:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534226400,
     "main":{
        "temp":292.3,
        "temp_min":291.706,
        "temp_max":292.3,
        "pressure":1020.99,
        "sea_level":1027.42,
        "grnd_level":1020.99,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.6
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.52,
        "deg":294.505
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 06:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534237200,
     "main":{
        "temp":291.07,
        "temp_min":290.77,
        "temp_max":291.07,
        "pressure":1020.65,
        "sea_level":1027.03,
        "grnd_level":1020.65,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.3
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":1.31,
        "deg":225.5
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 09:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534248000,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.286,
        "temp_min":293.286,
        "temp_max":293.286,
        "pressure":1020.78,
        "sea_level":1027.17,
        "grnd_level":1020.78,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"02d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":8
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.83,
        "deg":234.501
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 12:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534258800,
     "main":{
        "temp":298.671,
        "temp_min":298.671,
        "temp_max":298.671,
        "pressure":1020.76,
        "sea_level":1027.15,
        "grnd_level":1020.76,
        "humidity":92,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.71,
        "deg":259.5
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 15:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534269600,
     "main":{
        "temp":300.7,
        "temp_min":300.7,
        "temp_max":300.7,
        "pressure":1019.76,
        "sea_level":1026.18,
        "grnd_level":1019.76,
        "humidity":83,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":24
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.66,
        "deg":285.503
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":1.11
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 18:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534280400,
     "main":{
        "temp":298.464,
        "temp_min":298.464,
        "temp_max":298.464,
        "pressure":1019.68,
        "sea_level":1025.97,
        "grnd_level":1019.68,
        "humidity":83,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":48
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.27,
        "deg":289.504
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":1.61
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 21:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534291200,
     "main":{
        "temp":297.882,
        "temp_min":297.882,
        "temp_max":297.882,
        "pressure":1020,
        "sea_level":1026.37,
        "grnd_level":1020,
        "humidity":82,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":36
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.37,
        "deg":275.004
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":0.13
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 00:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534302000,
     "main":{
        "temp":295.242,
        "temp_min":295.242,
        "temp_max":295.242,
        "pressure":1021.11,
        "sea_level":1027.53,
        "grnd_level":1021.11,
        "humidity":94,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":802,
           "main":"Clouds",
           "description":"scattered clouds",
           "icon":"03n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":32
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":1.26,
        "deg":313.002
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 03:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534312800,
     "main":{
        "temp":294.05,
        "temp_min":294.05,
        "temp_max":294.05,
        "pressure":1021.27,
        "sea_level":1027.77,
        "grnd_level":1021.27,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.46,
        "deg":274.504
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 06:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534323600,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.495,
        "temp_min":293.495,
        "temp_max":293.495,
        "pressure":1021.36,
        "sea_level":1027.7,
        "grnd_level":1021.36,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.01,
        "deg":277.505
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 09:00:00"
],
"city":{
  "id":4347778,
  "name":"Baltimore",
  "coord":{
     "lat":39.2909,
     "lon":-76.6108
  },
  "country":"US",
  "population":620961
 }
  }
```

Comment: Or this code returns null `return weatherWrapper.getforecastWeatherLists();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe after you print the log an exception happens when you try to convert the JSON object try to print a log before your return value

```
Log.e("something",weatherWrapper.getforecastWeatherLists().size()+"")
   return weatherWrapper.getforecastWeatherLists();
```

most likely you have JSON cast exception

try to log also in the catch to see what happened

```
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("catch","error")

        }
```

Comment: @ksb please print the exception message

Comment: Here is the exception message I am getting: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 224 path $.list[0].weather

Comment: @ksb please show me your ForecastWeatherListWrapper class also log this                     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
Log.e("response",bufferedReader.toString)

Comment: I just added the wrapper code to the main body of my original post.

Comment: please add Log.e("response",bufferedReader.toString)  after bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

Comment: cloud you print the URL

Comment: The URL I’m testing is as follows: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecastq=baltimore&APPID=api_key_value. It could be I can’t use the url because of my current location for the next week.

Comment: your problem is simple, the object that you pass not in the same structure that in JSON object response if you could provide for me the response and your class it will be easy to solve your problem

Comment: I just provided the GSON code and the JSON raw data. I think this is what you need.

Comment: @ksb change 
private Weather weather = null;
in your ForecastWeatherList class
to 
private List<Weather> weather = null;

Comment: I added the following changes: @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<Weather> weather = null;

Comment: But then ended with the following information in my logcat: 08-24 01:03:12.166 4361-4418/com.ksburneytwo.weathertest E/GetWeatherAync: Response code:200 ; 
08-24 01:03:12.166 4361-4418/com.ksburneytwo.weathertest E/response: java.io.BufferedReader@ddf1522;
08-24 01:03:12.258 4361-4418/com.ksburneytwo.weathertest E/catch: error ;
08-24 01:03:12.258 4361-4418/com.ksburneytwo.weathertest I/System.out: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ ;
08-24 01:03:12.259 4361-4361/com.ksburneytwo.weathertest E/GetWeatherAync: Result is null

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your URL, I think. You need to pass arguments like this, did you forget to pass appid? -

> https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Are you sure that you get the proper response from the URL? If yes, check if your AsyncTask returns null

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<ForecastWeatherList> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "populate UI recycler view with gson converted data");
                listener.afterSearch(result);
            } else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Result is null");
                // check if this Log shows up?
           }
        }
```

Change your Service URL

> this.serviceUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q="
>   + "Baltimore" +"&appid="+api_key

Comment: Yes I just checked. I am getting "Result is null" in my logcat.

Answer (score 0):

the error in your response.
your code

```
ForecastWeatherListWrapper weatherWrapper = new Gson().fromJson(bufferedReader, ForecastWeatherListWrapper.class);
```

convert response to custom object.
so the response must begin with "{"
but your response begin with array "["

you have to fix your response or make your custom object expect array like that

```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<ForecastWeatherListWrapper>>() {
        }.getType();
        if (!bufferedReader.equals("")) {
         ForecastWeatherListWrapper weatherWrapper = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, type);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but now I'm getting: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: can you print your response and ForecastWeatherListWrapper class

you can use POSTMAN to read the response